# Resource Config in JSF framework

Tags: java, xml, jsf

Do anyone know how to configure resource-config.xml in JSF application.

For a new enhancement i have started configuring resource-config.xml, i tried placing it under META-INF folder, WEB-INF/classes, java source root directory. Neither one worked out for me. Resource config file is not recognized even if it is in the build path.

Can anyone guide me in configuring the same?

Thanks in advance.!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resource-config>
    <resource class="org.richfaces.renderkit.html.images.GrowlBackground">
        <name>org.richfaces.renderkit.html.images.GrowlBackground</name>
    </resource>
    <resource class="org.richfaces.renderkit.html.images.GrowlCloseButton">
        <name>org.richfaces.renderkit.html.images.GrowlCloseButton</name>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <name>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/images/info.png</name>
        <path>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/images/info.png</path>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <name>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/jquery.gritter.xcss</name>
        <path>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/jquery.gritter.xcss</path>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <name>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/growl.js</name>
        <path>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/growl.js</path>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <name>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/images/error.png</name>
        <path>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/images/error.png</path>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <name>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery/jquery.js</name>
        <path>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery/jquery.js</path>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <name>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery.gritter.js</name>
        <path>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery.gritter.js</path>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <name>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/images/warn.png</name>
        <path>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/images/warn.png</path>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <name>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/images/fatal.png</name>
        <path>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/images/fatal.png</path>
    </resource>
</resource-config>
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception on server console?

Comment: no. my console does'nt display any exception. some of the resources that i mapped in the config did'nt load on screen.!!

Comment: Maybe trivial questions... Have you checked existence of `resource-config.xml` in deployed directory? Or in war file?

Comment: yup, i can find the resources-config.xml in the deployed directory!

Comment: Possibly you can set the highest log level (`TRACE` or `FINEST` depends on your logger) to check whether `resource-config.xml` is used or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in META-INF.

Attached is a link to [CDK](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/cdkguide/html_single/) - Component Development Kit (CDK) which is a sub-project of RichFaces

there is a description of the configuration and path of resource-config.xml, used in development. hopefully it will shed light on your problem.

could you please post resource-config.xml? maybe there is an issue there?

--- Edit

If you develop with richfaces maybe try `src/main/config/resources` as suggested at [Developer Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/cdkguide/html_single/) section 4?

--- Edit

another source that might help [registering components with rich](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/cdkguide/html/register.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have included the content of resources-config.xml in the question.

Comment: i tried it by placing in META-INF folder but it doesn't works. No exception is also thrown.!!!

Comment: @radkrish added another source that can be usefull in registering a component

Comment: @radkrish If you see only some of your definitions, have you tried deleting cache (IDE AND Server (delete ears wars  etc directly . and then re deploy),)